# LoginView Control to show logged in view only for specific user's

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

So am using LoginView Control. This is what I know, if a user is logged in it will show Loggedin View of the template otherwise it shows AnonymousTemplate. This works on my page. I have used this on multiple pages.

Now my question is:

1. Is there a way I can restrict the loggedin view from displaying for non-members even if they are logged in. In other words, The loggedin view should be display only for typeA members and not typeB.
2. Is there a way I can programmatically hide Loggedin/AnonymousTemplate for specific user's.
   example: In Code behind:

   ```
   If(type of member == A) then
      Loggedin.visible = true
   else
    loggedin.visible = false
   end if
   ```

I know #2 doesn't seem to be right, but I don't know which is the best possible way ?

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
       <AnonymousTemplate>
             Please log in for personalized information.
       </AnonymousTemplate>
       <LoggedInTemplate>
             Thanks for logging in 
             <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
       </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: can't you set `LoginView1.Visible` property?

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I want. What I want is, I need AnonymousTemplate visible property and loggedIntemplate visible property which is not available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [the `RoleGroups` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.rolegroups.aspx).

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
   <AnonymousTemplate>
      (Content for anonymous users here)
   </AnonymousTemplate>
   <LoggedInTemplate>
      (Content for non-members here)
   </LoggedInTemplate>
   <RoleGroups>
      <asp:RoleGroup Roles="member">
         <ContentTemplate>
            (Content for members here)
         </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:RoleGroup>
   </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

If you don't want to show anything for a particular template, leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

while Richards answer provide better way to handle role based `asp:LoginView`

if you have more complex logic to set visibility of the control you can do it from the code behind as below

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
       <div id ="test1" runat="server">testing ....</div> 
    </AnonymousTemplate>
```

And then

```
var item = HeadLoginView.AnonymousTemplate;

var testDiv= HeadLoginView.FindControl("test1");
testDiv.Visible = true;
```